# Put Some Folder as PATH in Windows CE

Tags: path, windows-ce, registry

Someone can help me!, how to put some folder as PATH in the Windows CE, more specifically an HPC 2000(Jornada 720), put in the PATH like in Windows XP or 2000 or Vista, that you only run like **javac** or **ruby** in the *cmd* and the program runs. Remember that if it have to use the Registry Editor i have one installed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows CE does not support environment variables, nor does it have a notion of a working folder.  Everything must be done with a fully qualified path.

Comment: Because i want this PATH for using with Ruby for Windows CE, because is soo boring all times get to the folder of Ruby and run it.